# Motion tracking in screen recording

Tags: motion

I'm experimenting with motion tracking and screencasts. The motion tracker in Motion 5 has problems tracking a very basic shape though. I was wondering if someone may know why and how I could get the tracker to work properly?
The problem is that as soon as I hit analyze the tracker analyzes two or three frames then stops. I tried a couple of different settings but couldn't get it to work.

[Here's an example image](http://twitpic.com/a3w2b5)

The lower half shows a tracking point sitting on one of Motion's "suggested" tracking points.

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed any tutorials for this? Such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGeG5vvonHw)?

Comment: Yes. As I said the problem seems to be the kind of video. Real video recordings are quite different from "static" screen captures, i.e. apps.

Comment: I’m curious if you’ve made any progress with this?

Comment: I did not. I'm doing it all manual with interpolation.